# Divi theme custom module not updating at Frontend page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a [Custom Divi Module](https://wordpress.org/plugins/angelleye-paypal-for-divi/) through a plugin.  Our plugin adds a custom settings panel of its own, and then our Divi module utilizes some of the options/settings available in our settings to more quickly build and manage PayPal buttons through Divi.

For example, in our settings you can set up PayPal account ID(s), and then choose the account you want to use when adding a new PayPal button through the Divi module.  This is working great, however, when I then update the PayPal account ID value through our plugin settings, it does not take affect unless I go back to that specific module and re-save it.  Of course, that's exactly what we're trying to avoid doing.

Is there any way we can force the Divi modules related to our plugin to update?  Is this happening because of cache or localstorage maybe..??

**Check Video about the Issue in Below Link**

https://www.screencast.com/t/9mTDFz1jhbKK

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Please add the code snippet where you're pulling data from the plugin settings to add in the Divi module output for review.

Comment: Actually i  paced  this kind of saved problem in divi theme  two things is there  you can check i) while looping (reset_post_data)  ii) your page  builder container you can use standared width module.

Comment: @Samyappa reset _post_data is not working for this issue.. Can you explain me where to add that function in Divi modules or in my plugin file ?

Comment: @Tejas in your custom module query end of loop you need to add.

Comment: @Samyappa Yes thanks.. I will try and Give you my comments for that.